# How to check the first letter of a Button.Tag?

Tags: c#

So I ordered in my code buttons with a tag and the first letter of the tag decides if it is one group of buttons or another.
I need to check if a button is in one group or another and I am trying to check the first letter of the tag like a normal string with
`((Button)sender).Tag[0] == 'W'` and with `((Button)sender).Tag.FirstOrDefault() == 'W'` but the code gives me an error. What am I missing?

Comment: you need to see if `.Tag` is a string or not.

Comment: What error? Also, it's wpf, winforms, another front end? Please, add the respective tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to cast to string and compare to string, because Tag is an object

Answer (score 3):

Both in WPF and Winforms, `Tag` is declared as `object`. Therefore you need to cast it to string:

```
var button = ((Button)sender);
var tagString = (string)button.Tag;
if (tagString[0] == 'W') ...
```

If you are unsure if the Tag is always a string you can use an `as`-cast:

```
var button = ((Button)sender);
var tagString = button.Tag as string;
if (tagString != null && tagString[0] == 'W') ...
```

or with C# 7 you can also use pattern matching:

```
var button = ((Button)sender);
if (button.Tag is string tagString && tagString[0] == 'W') ...
```